# Как удалить картинку и/или заменить ее?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Как в Corona SDK заменить картинку другой или удалить ее, а затем поставить новую? Это общий вопрос, потому что с текстом у меня та же беда. Если старый сначала приравнивать к пустой строке, а потом изменять на новый, то он все же остается на экране.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать `image:removeSelf()` или `display:remove(image)` для того, чтобы удалить картинку и `image.isVisible = false` для того, чтобы ее скрыть. Затем добавлять новую вместо старой:

```
local imageOne = display.newImage('image1.png', 200, 200)
local imageTwo = display.newImage('image2.png', 200, 200)
imageTwo.isVisible = false -- скрыть вторую картинку

function imageOne(click) -- по касанию меняем imageOne на imageTwo
  if click.phase == 'began' then
    imageOne:removeSelf()
    imageOne = nil -- приравниваем к nil, чтобы освободить память
    imageTwo.isVisible = true
  end
end

imageOne:addEventListener('touch', imageOne)
```

Методы `object:removeSelf()` и `display:remove(object)` работают **со всеми объектами** на дисплее, включая текст (его можно править, кстати, пристыковав к объекту ".text", например: `myText.text = 'newText'`)